# .length property change inside a .substr()?

Tags: javascript

Here is some I just noticed and im asking if its normal. Im using a .length property inside a .substr(), but it seems like the value of .length change during the .substr(). Here is a example here : https://jsfiddle.net/L11yg3y0/1/

```
 var immastring = "Metaphysics"
 var test = immastring.substr(2,immastring.length-2);
 alert(test);
```

Shouldn't it output "taphysi" instead of "taphysics"? Because right now, it means that in the method .substr, they first remove the first two character, actualize the .length value and then remove the last two character.

I was just wondering because I already used this kind of method in other language like c++ and c#, but it wasn't working that way.

Comment: No because, the second parameter is the number of characters to take, not the index of the last character

Comment: Working as intended -> [`.substr(index, length)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: "`.length` property inside a `.substr()`" - you are not using it **inside** or **during** `.substr()` - the parameters are evaluated **before** the function is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`.substr`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) takes the start index and the **length** of the substring. `"Metaphysics"` has length 11, so `immastring.length - 2` is 9. `"taphysics".length` is indeed 9.

If you want to specify the end index, use [**`.substring`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead.

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I totally misconcepted it. Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has two substring methods, you picked the wrong one.

```
str.substr(start[, length])
```

vs

```
str.substring(indexStart[, indexEnd])
```

**References:**

- [MDN substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)
- [MDN substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: There's also [*slice*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.slice)…